# AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution() seems to be not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I read an article about the method AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution() and that it is a way of having an identity resolution without tracking and that when using it a change tracker different from that of the context is running in the background to resolve the entities those are referring to the same row to one instance.

I tried to verify that, by running the following code but the instances weren't resolved to one instance

```
// Initially the table is empty
Employee emp1 = new Employee()
{
    FirstName = "name1",
    LastName = "name2",
    Salary = 11111
};

context.Add(emp1);
context.SaveChanges();

Employee emp2 = (from e in context.Employees
                 where e.FirstName == "name1"
                 select e).SingleOrDefault();

// Identity resolution takes place
Console.WriteLine(emp1 == emp2); // True

Employee emp3 = (from e in context.Employees
                 where e.FirstName == "name1"
                 select e).AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution().SingleOrDefault();

// Expected to give True due to using AsNoTrackingWtihIdentityResolution()
Console.WriteLine(emp1 == emp3); // but found False

Employee emp4 = (from e in context.Employees
                 where e.FirstName == "name1"
                 select e).AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution().SingleOrDefault();

// Also no identity resolution happened
Console.WriteLine(emp4 == emp3); // False
```

**The reference comparison only gave true when the two compared instances (which are resolved to one instance) were tracked by the context change tracker, while the other instances weren't resolved to one instance. I'm using EF core 8.0.2**

So Now:

- Why the instances referring to the same row weren't resolved to one instance when using the method AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution() with their queries as it is one of its expected functionalities?
- Why there exists a standalone tracker running in the background when using this method such that one of the targets of using this method was to stop any tracking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution` do not use cached (tracked) entities and your tests are wrong.

This mode works only in query's scope. It reuses entities loaded by `Include` directive to fixup navigation properties and do not instantiate duplicate entities of the same type and with the same keys. That's why it is called `WithIdentityResolution`.

For example, if you have the following classes:

```cs
class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

class Orders
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

And query:

```cs
var result = context.Employees
   .Include(e => e.Orders)
        .ThenInclude(o => o.Employee) // can be omitted, just shows what we are trying to load
   .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution();
```

It means that every loaded Employee, will have Orders with initialised `Employee` navigation property with the same reference using Identty Resolution.

The same query without `.ThenInclude(o => o.Employee)` also should intilialize Orders's `Employee` property because Employeee are loaded in query and Identity Resolution can find them in query's scope for initilization.

Using just `AsNoTracking()` will instantiate for every Order new Employee object.

IOW, this method is useful if you are loading big graph of objects, it may reduce memory usage and query complexity.

Comment: Yep, a simpler example would be fetching Orders from context.Orders and including Employee. With `AsNoTracking`, each employee entity would be a distinct object, even if if they point to the same row in the DB. `AsNoTrackingWIthIdentityResolution` will ensure all employee references for the same employee on the orders are given the same employee object reference. They key, as you pointed out is that it applies only within the scope of that single query. If the OP wants references between queries they should be using a tracking query.